# Tapping MGLPolygon should forward tap to MGLAnnotation at same coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I have a `MGLAnnotation` with a `MGLPolygon` added below it to give a circular shape around the annotation.

However, when I tap the annotation, the `mapView:didSelectAnnotation:` method will return a `MGLPolygon` when I really want to be tapping the `MGLAnnotation`.

Is it possible to forward the taps from the `MGLPolygon` to the `MGLAnnotation`?

Answer (score 1):

I realized I just needed to add the following delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)mapView:(MGLMapView *)mapView shapeAnnotationIsEnabled:(MGLShape *)annotation {

    return NO;

}
```